# Can't use HAL Libraries because of this error

Tags: c, stm32, stm32f4, stm32cubemx, stm32cubeide

I'm currently learning to code STM32F446RE Nucleo in STM32CubeIDE. I was trying to use completed libraries from github. HAL libraries seemed useful but I get stuck on inclusion errors. I fix one and another one spawns. Recently I keep getting this one. I keep getting the error from compiler whenever I try to use the HAL libraries in an application. Anyone know how can I fix it ?

> stm32f4xx_hal_conf.h : no such file or directory

I found this header file in main "inc" folder but I can't include it, since my driver header files are in another file.

Comment: What's in your include path?

Comment: Quote: "This file should be copied to the application folder and renamed to stm32f4xx_hal_conf.h".  http://www.disca.upv.es/aperles/arm_cortex_m3/llibre/st/STM32F439xx_User_Manual/stm32f4xx__hal__conf_8h_source.html

Comment: What is meant by "Application folder"? Is that the src file that has main.c ?